# Reg Expression to validate name C#

Tags: c#, regex

I tried many different set of regex to validate usual names but none worked.
I want to only validate and allow comma, ' - and .   That all.
I am working on MVC using C# in Model class.  I tired below Regex and modified it differently but it is not working.

```
   [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z.,-' ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Not in correct format ")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Please also let me know if the same can be use in javascript  or jQuery.

Comment: . and - have special meaning in regex. They need to be escaped. Maybe try some things on regex101.com. they also explain the different regex parts.

Comment: This is a bad idea, IMO, and could be argued as racist - it is certainly at a minimum culturally ignorant. The range of characters used in real names is **much** bigger than this, and you're forcing people to give up their real name to use your system. If someone tells you their name (in unicode): *believe them* (unless full external identity validation is required, for example banks, but that applies identically to ASCII names). I *might* forgive `\w`, but I'd still check further to see what I am omitting.

Comment: It's better to have the regex in check for some characters (?  / * etc.) as against having it in a wide check for all special characters.

Comment: Some examples for what @MarcGravell noted can be seen [here](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)

Comment: And here some [W3C recommendations](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names.en.html)

Comment: Marc, that is these are the requirements.   During my search I have seen how the name regex is being created to cover other names and they also restrict how and when comma or - should be place.  So my concern is not that.  This site is not for public. It is private and those who uses the app are being paid. So they would have to be careful when they type the name. And we try to avoid some of the errors they may put in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is having `-` not as the last character in `[]`. It assumes it is a range. I your case any character between `,` and `'` but `,` is after `'` in ASCII so no characters.

I suggest you use [the following](https://regex101.com/r/JU5tAB/1):

```
"[A-Za-z., '-]+"
```

Comment: This seem to be working but wonder y someone down arrow the answer.  I would test little bit more and comeback to it.

Comment: I have noticed that some stackoverflow people are unaware of how limited their knowledge is.